# How to debug an error of "The method or Matcher in the type X is not applicable for the arguments"?

Tags: java, spring, junit, annotations, junit4

```
public class JUnitTest {
    @Autowired ApplicationContext context;

    static Set<JUnitTest> testObjects = new HashSet<JUnitTest>();
    static ApplicationContext contextObject = null;

    @Test public void test3() {
        assertThat(testObjects, not(hasItem(this)));
        testObjects.add(this);

        assertThat(contextObject, either(is(nullValue())).or(is(this.context))); //error
        contextObject = this.context;
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
The method or(Matcher< ? super Object >) in the type
CombinableMatcher.CombinableEitherMatcher< Object> is not applicable for the
arguments (Matcher< ApplicationContext>)
```

How to fix this code?

Answer (score -1):

You can specify a type as your parameter to `nullValue` to have it return the appropriate type.

```
assertThat(contextObject, either(is(nullValue(ApplicationContext.class))).or(is(this.context)));
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Please don't forget to upvote and accept this answer if you found it useful.